# Javascript preventDefault() ignored on second submission

Tags: javascript

I'm experiencing some issues preventing form submission when I try to submit an invalid situation.

Assume I have the following code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    $("form").on("submit",function (event) {
        $("#errorDiv").fadeOut(null, null, function () {
            OnSubmitForm(event)
        });

    })
}


function OnSubmitForm(event) {
    let items = $("#mytable").dxDataGrid("instance").getSelectedRowsData();
    if (items.length == 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (items.some(item => item.booleanProperty != true)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let badItems = items.filter(item => item.booleanProperty != true).map(item => item.id);
        let divText = "<strong>bad items:<br>"
            + badItems.join("<br>") +"</strong>";

        $("#errorDiv").html(divText);
        $("#errorDiv").fadeIn();
    }
}
```

My intention is to `fadeOut` the `div` I use to display the error, and when the animation is complete I call `OnSubmitForm`, passing `event` to it.

The flow of my actions is the following:

1. I click the submit button
2. `fadeOut` kicks in
3. `OnSubmitForm` is called
4. the `else if` condition is `true`, so the block is executed
5. `event.preventDefault()` works
6. I click again the submit button
7. Form is submitted

What's happening?

Plus, I've noted that the result of `event.isPreventedByDefault()` returns `false` before the first `event.preventDefault()`, then it returns `true`, because the event was already prevented once, according to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented).

**More info**
I forgot to mention that if I do the same violating the first "rule" (first `if` statement) everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `OnSubmitForm` when the fade out is complete. This happens **after** the `submit` event handler function has *finished* without preventing the default behaviour.

The form has already been submitted by the time you try to stop it.

Comment: Then why does it work always on the first time? Is it just a coincidence?

Comment: @magicleon — Presumably the errordiv is not shown first time, so there is no delay before prevent default is called.

Comment: Yeah you're right the div is hidden in the beginning. But... Why does the first if always work? Is it because is a faster operation so it has the time to catch up and prevent the event before the submit finishes?

Comment: The callback is called synchronously if there are no elements to operate on.